# Image not able to uploaded to Amazon S3 server

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, image-uploading, memorystream

I am using the below code to upload image file Amazon AWS S3 server..

```
using (var msImage = new MemoryStream(arrayImage))
using (var msImageL1 = new MemoryStream())
using (var bmImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(msImage))
using (var bmPicture01 = new Bitmap(924, 693))
using (Graphics gPicture01 = Graphics.FromImage(bmPicture01))
{
    using (IAmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast1))
    {
        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = "sample/5.jpg",
            InputStream = msImage
        };

        s3client.PutObject(putObjectRequest);

    }

    gPicture01.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    gPicture01.DrawImage(bmImage, 0, 0, 924, 693);
    bmPicture01.Save(msImageL1, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    using (IAmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast1))
    {
        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = "sample/6.jpg",
            InputStream = msImageL1
        };

        s3client.PutObject(putObjectRequest);

    }
}
```

The first code, which is uploading "5.jpg" is working fine, and uploading successfully. But the other code is now working and giving exception that,

```
Message=The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
Message=Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.
```

I am using Amazon Web Services SDK for .NET version 2.0.2.3

Please suggest what might be going wrong here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there hasn't been any other answer and my first response got deleted because it "does not really answer the question", I'm going to try and rephrase it.

You said:

> Please suggest what might be going wrong here..

My suggestion is that there is nothing wrong with you code.  Instead it's a possible bug with version 2.0.1 and later. See https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=139612&tstart=0 (requires log in).  I've tried with version 2.0.2.3 and the bug is still there.

You can test this by using a previous version.

Comment: After many hours, hating myself and wondering why Amazon despised me so, I can confirm that this is the answer. The new SDK is broken for PutObject calls that pass a stream as the parameter. I tried everything to fix, but reverting to an older version of the SDK was the only solution.

Comment: An addenda: The same thread now says that it is fixed in 2.0.4. Also note Pavel's workaround if you are still stuck with 2.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `bmPicture01.Save(msImageL1, ImageFormat.Jpeg);` saves the bitmap to a string but doesn't reset the position of the stream to 0. You will need to do that before passing the stream to `PutObject`.